# Why doesn't set_titles produced a title (Seaborn and Factorplot)?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is the code I'm using. It's a self_contained code that can be copied and pasted.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



### Load the Titanic dataset
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

### Divide the data by sex; male and female

male = titanic[titanic.sex == 'male']
female = titanic[titanic.sex == 'female']




### Now use groupby to group by fare//5 and then create a column with the  survival rate for each group

male_chart= male.groupby([male.fare // 5]).survived.mean().reset_index()
female_chart= female.groupby([female.fare // 5]).survived.mean().reset_index()



#Plot male_chart
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
g = sns.factorplot(x='fare', y= 'survived',  data=male_chart,
               size=6, aspect =3 ,kind="bar", palette="muted")

g.despine(left=True)
g.set_ylabels("Survival Probability")
g.set_xlabels('Fare *5')
g.set_titles('Males')   # set_title doesn't produce "Males" on the chart itself



#sns.plt.title('Males')   #This code seems to work but not sure why it does. 


#plot: female_chart

h= sns.factorplot(x='fare', y= 'survived',  data=female_chart,
               size=6, aspect =3 ,kind="bar", palette="muted")
h.despine(left=True)
h.set_ylabels("survival probability")
h.set_xlabels('fare *5')
h.set_titles('Females')  #Once again doesn't work.
#sns.plt.title('Females')  #but this works
plt.show()
```

I'm not getting any errors while running  the "set_titles" line but it's not producing the title on the graph itself. 
How am I using set_title incorrectly? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: `set_titles` is used when you have `col`/`row` faceting, which you're not using here. You want `g.ax.set_title()`.

Comment: I do that when I want to communicate useful information but don't have time to write up a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

###### set_titles ("NName of plot") works only in `FacetGrid` where you have x columns or y rows.

(E.g)

```
facet_grid = sns.relplot(data=data, x = "X", y = "Y", col = "Split"). set_titles("Works fine")
```

###### if your plot isn't `FacetGrid` and you uses `set_titles` it will not show the title

### For Example

**will not work**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))  
sns.displot(df["GPA"],kind='kde').set_titles("Distribution of Data")
```

**Works Fine**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,6)) # works fine
sns.displot(df["GPA"],kind='kde').set(title='Title of Plot')
```

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.set_titles.html

Comment: Your first example is `set_title`, but the question is about `set_titles` (with "s") which is different. As mwaskom said, `set_titles` (with "s") is only possible if you've faceted with the `col` or `row` params.

Comment: @tdy thanks tdy  it was typo, do you think my answer is  just a reputation and i need to remove it or i should keep it,

Comment: But now your edited code does not work. `set_titles` does not work on a regular (non-faceted) plot without `col` or `row`. That's exactly what Moondra was asking about.

Comment: @tdy i see i will remove my answer

Comment: @tdy my suggestion is he can use  `set(title='Title of Plot')` to be specific

Comment: You don't need to remove it. You can just fix it as mwaskom said, to make it a faceted plot using `col` or `row`. The issue is that your first code example is simply wrong/broken right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250443/discussion-between-mohamed-fathallah-and-tdy).